# Returned object from another class method

Tags: java, android, oop, android-volley

I feel like this is a very basic concept missunderstanding. In my Android app I make HTTP requests using Volley lib. At first I made the requests through a JsonObjectRequest in the Activity code and worked right, but now I separated the request code in a class apart so I can call it from any Activity. The new class has a method that returns the requested JSONObject but any "json action" I do over the returned object ends in an error.

Here is the new class code, JSONRequests:

```
public class JSONRequests {

  private JSONObject mResponse;
  private String mURL = "https://myurl.com/";

  public JSONObject getJSONObject(final String credentials, final String path) {
    final JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(mURL.concat(path), null,
      new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          mResponse = response;
          try {
           Log.d("RESPONSE", mResponse.getString("id")); // It works here
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      },

      new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
      }
    ) {

      @Override
      public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
        return headers;
      }
    };
    MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(mRequest);
    return mResponse;
  }
}
```

And here is how I call getJSONObject from MyActivity:

```
JSONRequests mRequest = new JSONRequests();
JSONObject mInfo = mRequest.getJSONObject(mEncodedCredentials, mPath);
try {
  Log.d("RESPONSE", mInfo.getString("id")); // This doesn't work
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When in the Activity file, I used "response" as a JSONObject and it worked, but now separated it won't. I don't know if is a error with JSONObject or just that I'm not getting the returned object in the correct way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no way to do this(well there is one but will cause ANR - that's why NetworkOnMainThreadException exists) ... you have to use callback ... come back here if you understand the callback concept bacuase without this it's like telling the blind man about colours ... anyway such callback/listener already exists in your code - you have to learn how to use it properly

Comment: @Selvin I'm kind of new to Android/Java, I'm reading about callbacks and I think I'll understand how to do it now I know what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: tip: all code that you would normally putted after the synchronous call have to be putted inside callback's `onResponse`/`onDone`/`onFinish`/`onWhateverWhatMeansThatJobIsDone` method when you are using asynchronous call